# Where does web server keep the session data exactly?

Tags: web-services, mobile

And in case of mobile phone internet access, how does the web server identify one visitor from another, through phone number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stored on the server. PHP stores the session data internally depending on how you've configured `session.save-path`

See here for more info : http://us.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path

Mobile phone internet access works just the same as any other HTTP access. The browser initiates a connection and the session is managed in the normal way. Phone numbers don't come into play at all

Answer (score 1):

> how does the web server identify one visitor from another, through phone number?

**No** they differentiate users from `cookie` ,  it saves data that will map client to session on server.